# Rails - Paginate an array, page-by-page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a question on the "workflow" of a tutorial app I am working on, using Rails 4.

Let's say I have 1,000 templates and various groups that will access those templates.  For example, if I wanted to retrieve all the records for **'Group 1'**, I might get the following 5 records:

```
  Templates:
    id   |   content    |    group_id
    23   |   "a"        |       1
    44   |   "b"        |       1
    99   |   "c"        |       1
    104  |   "d"        |       1
    137  |   "e"        |       1
```

Now that I have the 5 records associated with group 1, I would like to have 5 separate pages lined up, all in a row.  Whereby, the user would first see the page for `id: 23`, then click "Submit".  Upon hitting "Submit", the next page displayed would be for `id: 44`, then this would be continued all the way until the user has gotten to `id: 137`.

What is the best way to achieve this workflow?  I suppose this is something similar to a survey being filled out, or a tutorial being completed.  Would I need to use ajax to accomplish this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use some kind of pagination gem for this, my favorite is [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate). It's super easy to use.

Comment: Another alternative is the well supported [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) gem.